# How to use SSE Intrinsics to subtract two different parts of the same array?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, optimization, sse

I have a loop with another loop inside it doing some calculations from arrays. I want to optimise the code using SSE however there are multiple parts which are confusing me, the largest of which is stated in the question title.

The original code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        float kx = a[j] - a[i];
        float ky = b[j] - b[i];
        float kz = c[j] - c[i];
        float k2 = kx*kx + ky*ky + kz*kz + eps;
        float k2inv = 1.0f / sqrt(k2);
        float k6inv = k2inv * k2inv * k2inv;
        float s = m[j] * k6inv;
        ax[i] += s * kx;
        ay[i] += s * ky;
        az[i] += s * kz;    
    }
}
```

How do I convert this code into SSE instructions? The code I came up with is below but after I realised I was going to need to subtract two parts of the same array I was totally stumped:

My attempt:

```
float *x = malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
float *y = malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
float *z = malloc(sizeof(float) * N); 

for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        __m128 rxj = _mm_load_ps(x+j);
        __m128 rxi = _mm_load_ps(x+i);
        __m128 ry = _mm_load_ps(y+j);
        __m128 ry = _mm_load_ps(y+i);
        __m128 rz = _mm_load_ps(z+j);
        __m128 rz = _mm_load_ps(z+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: future readers: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735546/optimisation-using-sse-intrinsics for the followup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need any new arrays to vectorize.  After applying the `restrict` keyword, (and changing `sqrt` to `sqrtf`), your original source [auto-vectorizes with clang 3.7 with `-ffast-math`](http://goo.gl/1DE3qf) (but not gcc 5.3).  You should probably just use an OpenMP pragma or something to enable auto-vectorization over i or j.

```
// auto-vectorizes with clang and icc, but not gcc :/
void ffunc(float *restrict ax, float *restrict ay, float *restrict az,
           const float *a, const float *b, const float *c,
           int N, float eps, const float *restrict m)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        float kx = a[j] - a[i];
        float ky = b[j] - b[i];
        float kz = c[j] - c[i];
        float k2 = kx*kx + ky*ky + kz*kz + eps;
#if 1   // better code when rsqrtps is used (with a refinement step)
        float k2inv = 1.0f / sqrtf(k2);
        float k6inv = k2inv * k2inv * k2inv;
        float s = m[j] * k6inv;
#else   // maybe better code when rcpps isn't used
        float k2sqrt = sqrtf(k2);
        float k6sqrt = k2sqrt * k2sqrt * k2sqrt;
        float s = m[j] / k6sqrt;
#endif
        ax[i] += s * kx;
        ay[i] += s * ky;
        az[i] += s * kz;    
    }
  }
}
```

#### See [my answer on the OP's followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35737027/224132) for a manually vectorized version that's significantly better than what gcc or clang do with this.

You might also get better code if you could give the compiler some alignment guarantees (esp. for gcc, which likes to do intro/outro blocks to reach an alignment boundary, instead of using unaligned ops.)

---

It looks like you can use SSE to do four iterations of the inner loop at once.  Doing four `i` values in parallel, or four `j` values in parallel, is fine because the result of one iteration isn't an input to another iteration.

So you'll have a vector with `a[i+3]  a[i+2]  a[i+1]  a[i]`  (from left (high elements) to right (low elements) in your vector).  You'll have three vectors that only change in the outer loop, and three that change every time through the inner loop.  You'll **broadcast `a[j]` to all positions of another vector** (outside the inner loop).

Actually, you might want to interchange your loops, so the accumulators (`ax[i] += ...`) can just sit in registers throughout the inner loop.  You'd have to load `m[j]` every time through the inner loop then, but that's balanced out by not having to load/store `ax[i]`, `ay[i]`, `az[i]` every time.

You should also consider how much precision you need in your inverse sqrt: There's a reciprocal sqrt instruction, and using that with one or maybe two newton-raphson iterations might be a throughput win.  Also, writing your source like this:

```
    // better code *if* the compiler isn't going to use rsqrtps
    // otherwise worse code
    float k2sqrt = sqrtf(k2);        // note the sqrtf to not request double-precision sqrt
    float k6sqrt = k2sqrt * k2sqrt * k2sqrt;
    float s = m[j] / k6sqrt;
```

does the same number of divisions (one), but with one fewer multiply.

Comment: Gcc does vectorize with --param vect-max-version-for-alias-checks=20, not sure how good the result is though.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Inner loop looks similar to clang's, but there's a huge amount of intro/outro.  clang typically just uses unaligned loads/stores, so the code runs full speed when the inputs happen to be aligned at run time.  gcc's strategy is only optimal if unaligned inputs are actually common, and problem sizes are large.  Modern x86 CPUs have fast enough unaligned support in HW.  (Since Nehalem, `movups` is as fast as `movaps` when used on aligned data.)